# Do all browsers interpret verbal colors equally?

Tags: css, web, browser

I'm working on my project and detect that I start using a lot of verbal colour names as a `background:whitesmoke;` `background:aliceblue`, etc.

Is this way safe? Do all browsers know that whitesmoke is #F5F5F5 or aliceblue is #f0f8ff? Or should I switch it to HEX?

Comment: No, that's why it is always better to use web safe colours.

Comment: Maybe you know is there an article about is the topic?

Comment: I read it somewhere... Let me find it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The colour names are mapped to hex values in the [CSS Color specification](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-color/#named-color) so any browser than follows the specification will do the same mapping.

The was [a suggestion recently](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/5284#issuecomment-653703998) that the colour of NavajoWhite be adjusted so that it's not the rather unfortunate `#FFDEAD`, but it was rejected as not being backward web compatible.

The general feeling among those who know them, think that the colour names are largely silly and their use is discouraged, but they're standardized anyway and we're stuck with what they are.